# 2008 / 2012 r2 mixed mode upgrade

Tags: windows, active-directory

We're planning to upgrade our ad infrastructure from 2008 R1 Standard to 2012 R2. In the past when adding domain controllers you changed the functional level to mixed mode, then after removing old domain controllers you change it native mode. Is this still the case or did Microsoft just do away with mixed mode / native mode?

I found a bunch of lists of available function levels on technet articles and 2012 "mixed mode" wasn't on the list, but nothing clearly stating mixed mode is gone and that there is no need to raise domains to a "mixed mode" or something similar in order to have server 2012 R2 domain controllers along side server 2008 domain controllers.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was only one mixed-mode Domain Functional Level and that was 2000. You didn't state what your current DFL and FFL is but there's only one scenario where you couldn't introduce W2K12 or W2K12 R2 Domain Controllers, and that scenario is if your current DFL and FFL is Windows 2000.

Here's a list of the various DFL's, FFL's and the supported Domain Controllers for each:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(v=ws.10).aspx